# Durable topic subscription and dead.letter.address and message redelievery

Tags: jms, rollback, jms-topic, dead-letter

I have jms topic, which has one or more durable subscriptions. 
I have situation when one subscriber causes roll-back and another success. Message lands in dead-letter-address.

After I resolve a bug and message should be able to proceed, I want to move message back to original destination (the topic). Problem is, that after I do that, all subscribers get message, not only the one, which failed.

Is it possible to resolve it somehow?

Just for information. I use JBoss eap 6.1 with HornetQ as jms provider.

Comment: What do you use at the client side? eg. spring-jms?

Comment: I use EJB3 Message driven bean. Why is that important?

Comment: When you are putting message back on the Topic may be you could add a message selector specific to particular client, so that only particular client could read this message.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I was thinking about that already. It might work. Disadvantage is, that here has to be made corrections in each MDB. I was wondering, if there is any "standard" method for this case.